# Graphhopper route direction weighting

Tags: java, graphhopper

Is it possible to write weighting based on direction? I see there is `reverse` parameter, but what does it means, and how can I compute it?

For example I have a straight route from South to North

```
(0)
 |
 |
 |
(1)
```

I need different weight from (1) to (0) and from (0) to (1).

==== Update

I've computed direction based on two last points of vehicle:

1. Input are two last points of vehicle
2. Base on two last points, I'm computing angle
3. Finding edge in place where is vehicle
4. Computing angle of edge based on geometry
5. Comparing two edges

Here is code in Scala:

```
def isReverseDirection(target: Point, previous: Point) = {
    val angle = RouteUtils.angleFromCoordinate(previous.lat, previous.long, target.lat, target.long)
    val edgeState = findEdge(target.lat, target.long)
    val pl = edgeState.fetchWayGeometry(3)

    val edgeAngle = RouteUtils.angleFromCoordinate(pl.getLat(0), pl.getLongitude(0), pl.getLat(pl.getSize - 1),
      pl.getLongitude(pl.getSize - 1))

    Math.abs(edgeAngle - angle) > 90
}
```

I've tested this solution and it seems to be working. I need to implement `Car2FlagEncoder`. In red spot I've received blocking data from vehicle moving (0) -> (1). And then I'm computing routes from both sides:

[image: (0) -> (1)]

[image: (1) -> (1)]

Answer (score 1):

That is possible. You can store e.g. a forward and a backward speed as we've done in [Bike2WeightFlagEncoder](https://github.com/graphhopper/graphhopper/blob/master/core/src/main/java/com/graphhopper/routing/util/Bike2WeightFlagEncoder.java) to have slower speed up-hill compared to down-hill but has other applications like traffic influenced speeds for cars etc. See the [FastestWeighting](https://github.com/graphhopper/graphhopper/blob/master/core/src/main/java/com/graphhopper/routing/util/FastestWeighting.java#L53) on how to use this.

Background: The flags are already correctly swapped depending if from 0->1 or 1->0, this is done within the EdgeIterator implementation in GraphHopperStorage.

Still the `reverse` parameter has not yet influenced anything. This parameter can be `true` and `false` only for a bidirectional algorithm (for unidir algorithms it'll be always `false`) and so you need to take additionally care in the weighting for the reverse search that you read the reverse speed.

Comment: So if I will use `dijkstrabi` algorithm will I receive proper reverse parameters? And how can I compute this value manually, in case I wanted to change speed during runtime, is it based on angle?

Comment: Which value, the speed value? You can make it depending on stored values per edge, yes

Comment: No I meant `reverse`, I have a moving car, how can I compute his direction to be corresponding to this parameter?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Maybe something like this? https://github.com/graphhopper/graphhopper/issues/225

Comment: In my case I'm using custom weighting  in flexible mode. I have a data about traffic on roads but there is info about street side, how can I match reverse parametr to street side? For example I have a info that some street is blocked from 0 to 1, but for 1 to 0 is no cogestion and everyone can go normally. How can I block in weighting only side 0 to 1?

Comment: By flexible mode I meant setting `CHEnable` to `false`

Comment: You store this direction dependent information in the flags (again see the Bike2WeightFE) and the flagencoder will take all necessary 'swapping' actions via flagencoder.reverseFlags

Comment: Thank you for all support, I've checked the sources, and please correct me if I'm wrong: reverse = false only then when we are going from first point of edge (edge.fetchWayGeometry) to last of this point? When we are going opposite direction it will be true?

Comment: Again: reverse has nothing to do with 0->1 or 1->0 instead it is about the reverse search from the goal to the start which only occurs in bidirectional searches.

Comment: So is it possible to block only one street side during runtime? I saw you are  setting speed in graph (https://github.com/karussell/graphhopper-traffic-data-integration) but how can I detect if I should set speed or reverse speed?

Comment: You can find this out e.g. via the base node of EdgeIteratorState. 0->1 means: baseNode=0 and adjNode=1

Comment: I've updated question, I hope now it's clear. I made a few tests and it seems to be working, may be there is some better way to compute direction